# Json from Classes VB.net

Tags: json, vb.net, class

I edit my code. I'm trying to serialize a Json file based on these classes. My drawback is with the "Concept" class which is a list of articles that I must obtain from a "Line" table and serialize the field values into the public properties of the "concept" class. I publish what I've done so far. Any help + suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

```
  Public Class Folio
    Public Property serie As String
    Public Property folio As String
End Class

Public Class Emisor
    Public Property nit As String
End Class

Public Class Receptor
    Public Property nombre As String
    Public Property nit As String
    Public Property calle As String
    Public Property ciudad As String
    Public Property estado As String
    Public Property pais As String
    Public Property regimen_fiscal As String
    Public Property perfil As String
    Public Property email As String
    Public Property telefono As String
End Class

Public Class Concepto
    Public Property cantidad As String
    Public Property unidad As Integer
    Public Property concepto As String
    Public Property pu As String
    Public Property desc As Integer
    Public Property impuesto As String
    Public Property tasa As String
    Public Property ni As String
    Public Property importe As String
End Class

Public Class Retencione
    Public Property impuesto As String
    Public Property importe As String
    Public Property tasa As Integer
    Public Property clave As String
End Class

Public Class FacturaE
    Public Property folio As Folio
    Public Property emisor As Emisor
    Public Property receptor As Receptor
    Public Property referencia As String
    Public Property fecha_vencimiento As DateTime
    Public Property moneda As String
    Public Property moneda_vcambio As String
    Public Property subtotal As String
    Public Property impuestos As String
    Public Property descuentos As String
    Public Property total As String
    Public Property metodo_pago As String
    Public Property forma_pago As String
    Public Property condicionpago As String
    Public Property leyenda_fiscal As Integer
    Public Property conceptos As List(Of Concepto)
    Public Property retenciones As List(Of Retencione)
    Public Property huella As String
End Class
```

The code

```
Dim facturaJson As New FacturaE
        Dim bsObj As FacturaE = New FacturaE() With {
                        .folio = New Folio() With {
        .folio = "0000007",
        .serie = "E"},
                        .emisor = New Emisor() With {
        .nit = "379487548-7"},
                        .receptor = New Receptor() With {
        .nombre = "RESTAURANTE Y CAFETERIA EL GORDO",
        .nit = "37947878-5",
        .calle = "CR 15 7 43",
        .ciudad = "CURUMANI",
        .estado = "CESAR",
        .pais = "COL",
        .regimen_fiscal = "F",
        .perfil = "R",
        .email = "elcorreo@hotmail.com",
        .telefono = "3115827410"},
        .referencia = "0977245487", ' verificar a que hace "referencia"
        .fecha_vencimiento = "2020-10-21T00:00:00",
        .moneda = "COP",
        .moneda_vcambio = "1",
        .subtotal = "863470.68",
        .impuestos = "150379.43",
        .descuentos = "OO",
        .total = "",  ' SUMA DE IMPUESTOS, DESCUENTO, BASE
        .metodo_pago = "1",
        .forma_pago = "PUE",
        .condicionpago = "1",
        .leyenda_fiscal = 0},
                        .conceptos = New Concepto() With {
        .cantidad = "5.00",
        .unidad = 0,
        .concepto = "SOBRE DE SEGURIDAD",
        .pu = "5714.290000",
        .desc = "0",
        .impuesto = "5428.58",
        .tasa = "19.00",
        .ni = "PANDA17",
        .importe = "5714.290000"}

        ' Conceptos (Array) desde el detalle de conceptos (Articulos) en la factura
        ' tomados desde la capa de datos mediante SQL Debe generarse así en el JSON 
        ' usando la clase FacturaE --> Public Property: conceptos As Concepto()
        ' de la clase Publica Concepto.
        '------------------------------------<

        '.conceptos [
        '   {
        '       "cantidad": "3.00",
        '       "unidad": 0,
        '       "concepto": "PC J1 BLANCO BX200 UND",
        '       "pu": "43781.510000",
        '       "desc": 0,
        '       "impuesto": "24955.46",
        '       "tasa": "19.00",
        '       "ni": "BJ1",
        '       "importe": "131344.530000"
        '   },
        '   {
        '       "cantidad": "3.00",
        '       "unidad": 0,
        '       "concepto": "TAPABOCAS HOUSE CAJA X50 UND",
        '       "pu": "24000.000000",
        '       "desc": 0,
        '       "impuesto": "0.00",
        '       "tasa": "0.00",
        '       "ni": "7707320620811",
        '       "importe": "72000.000000"
        '   }
        '],

        Dim str As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bsObj, Formatting.Indented)
        ' Exporting .json file
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("E:\5-000007.json", str)
```

Comment: Welcome!
Please consider adding `vb.net` and/or any other appropriate tags to the question.
Thank you and good luck!

Comment: Just to be clear, you're problem is in relation to deserializing the json into the class structure you've created?  Are you able to show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Thank you Hursey for answering, No, the problem is not the deserialization of json, the Json I post is the model that I must serialize from Vb.net, I used an Online tool (https://jsonutils.com/) to create the classes based on json. My fundamental problem is that I don't know how to start building json using those classes. I've tried several things, but I don't start.

Comment: Dim folios As New Folio
        folios = New Folio
        With folios

            Dim folio As New List(Of Folio)
            With folio

            End With
        End With

        Dim str As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(folios, Formatting.Indented)
        ' exportamos a la carpeta destino
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("E:\JSON1.json", str)

Comment: You should edit that code into the question instead of posting it as a comment.